# Multiple get request parameters @PathVariable and @RequestAttribute with Micronaut?

Tags: java, micronaut

I have a get function in my controller with differents parameters:

**myinterface.java**:

```
public interface MyInterface {

   @Get(value = "/bob/{name}/params?surname={surname}")
   String getMyParam (
   @Parameter(name="name", required=true)
   @PathVariable("name") String name, 
   @NotNull 
   @Parameter(name="surname", required=true) 
   @Valid 
   @RequestAttribute(value="surname") String surname) {

   }
}
```

**mycontroller.java**:

```
public class MyController implements MyInterface {

   @Override
   public String getMyParam(String name, String surname) { return name + surname; }
}
```

But when i'm calling "http://localhost:8080/bob/marley/params?surname=lion" it's send a ERROR MESSAGE: Page Not Found.

When i'm work with optional parameters `/books{?max,offset}` it's work. Did i miss something?

Are PathVariable and RequestAttribute not mixable while doing query requests?

**EDIT 1**

When i remove the `?surname=={surname}` from the @Get value it occurs an "HttpClientResponseException: Require argument [String surname] not specified".

Comment: You shouldn't add query string params (`?surname={surname}`) to `@Get`-s value, `@RequestAttribute` in method's argument list is enough

Comment: It doesnt work. I have an "Required argument [String surname] not specified"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`surname` in your case is not request attribute but query value (parameter). So use `@QueryValue` annotation instead of `@RequestAttribute` and do not specify it in URL pattern.

So the controller implementation can look like this:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    @Get(value = "/bob/{name}/params")
    String getMyParam(String name, @QueryValue String surname) {
        return name + surname;
    }
}
```

---

Another thing is that `@NotNull` annotation for `surname` parameter is redundant. That parameter is required by default. If you want it as optional then it must be of `Optional` type like this:

```
@Get(value = "/bob/{name}/params")
String getMyParam(String name, @QueryValue Optional<String> surname) {
    return name + surname.orElse("");
}
```