# How i can get values in body request?

Tags: oauth-2.0, micronaut, x-www-form-urlencoded

i'm newbie with micronaut and can't get value in a body request.

I'm using "x-www-form-urlencoded", and i need get some values for use on authentication.

Controller:

```
@Controller
@Secured(SecurityRule.IS_AUTHENTICATED)
public class ControllerApi {
    @Post("/hello")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    public String helloPost(){

        return "POST hello ";
    }
}
```

AuthenticationProviderForm:

```
@Singleton
public class AuthenticationProviderForm implements AuthenticationProvider  {


    @Override
    public Publisher<AuthenticationResponse> authenticate(@Nullable HttpRequest<?> httpRequest,
                                                          AuthenticationRequest<?, ?> authenticationRequest) {
                   httpRequest.getBody();    //This return is "empty", and i need the values here.

    }
}
```

Request:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/hello' \
--header 'Origin: localhost' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic YWxhbjEyMzpjYWp1MTIz' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
--data-urlencode 'scope=TESTE' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=alan123' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=caju123'
```

Thanks !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57078482/7776688 look at that solution

Comment: @IEE1394 - I don't think that solution is accessing the body.  I think that is only dealing with uri variables.  Is that correct?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown yeah my fault i was a little confused by the url encoded data. I thaugt it also arrived as url parameter (@QueryValue) in the backend?

Comment: Guys, thanks everyone... I'm using "Authorization: Basic", but i think than dont have body!

Answer (score 0):

Try seting your header to accept urlencoded content type:

```
httpRequest.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
```

Comment: I can't do this, my httpRequest dont have this method...   =/

( import io.micronaut.http.HttpRequest )

Comment: "I can't do this, my httpRequest dont have this method... =/ ( import io.micronaut.http.HttpRequest )"- does `myRequest.getHeaders().add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")` work?

Answer (score 0):

The body will always be empty inside of a `AuthenticationProvider`

```
Since version 2.5, the Micronaut Framework executes the filters
and then it reads the HTTP Request’s body. 
SecurityFilter evaluates the beans of type SecurityRule. 
Because of that, SecurityRule cannot rely on HTTP Request’s body 
because the Micronaut Framework has not read the body yet.
```

Comment: This answer is likely why you're not getting an httpRequest.  You'll notice in my answer that I'm hitting the `/login` endpoint directly, and not using basic auth, which must behave differently as I'm getting a body.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where I needed to get at a captcha that was included in the post body.  Here's what I ended up doing to get access to it.

my post looks like this:

```
### Login with captcha
POST http://localhost:8081/login
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

username=myuser&password=mypass&captcha=12345
```

my authProvider's authenticate method:

```
    @Override
    public Publisher<AuthenticationResponse> authenticate(@Nullable HttpRequest<?> httpRequest,
                                                          AuthenticationRequest<?, ?> authRequest)
    {
        if (httpRequest == null)
            return Mono.empty();

        final Optional<LoginCredentials> loginRequestOptional = httpRequest.getBody(LoginCredentials.class);
        if (loginRequestOptional.isEmpty())
        {
            return Mono.empty();
        }
        else
        {
            final LoginCredentials loginRequest = loginRequestOptional.get();
            return Flux.create(emitter -> {
                final AuthenticationResponse authResponse = authenticateHavingCaptcha(loginRequest, httpRequest);
                emitter.next(authResponse);
                emitter.complete();
            });
        }
```

and the LoginCredentials class looks like this:

```
@Introspected
public class LoginCredentials extends UsernamePasswordCredentials
{
    @NotBlank
    @NotNull
    private String captcha;


    public String getCaptcha()
    {
        return captcha;
    }


    public void setCaptcha(String captcha)
    {
        this.captcha = captcha;
    }
}
```

I don't know why you're getting an empty httpRequest, but hopefully this will help you on your way.